# copy-of vs. xsl:attribute

Tags: xslt

XML:

`<rating>
    <input type="radio" class="cmtRating" name="463[rating]" value="1" />
    <input type="radio" class="cmtRating" name="463[rating]" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" class="cmtRating" name="463[rating]" value="3" />
    <input type="radio" class="cmtRating" name="463[rating]" value="4" />
    <input type="radio" class="cmtRating" name="463[rating]" value="5" />
    </rating>`

How to add id to radio buttons?
This doesn't work:

`<xsl:copy-of select=".">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">rating-input-1-<xsl:value-of select="./@value"/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy-of>`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: try`<input type="radio" class="cmtRating" name="463[rating]" tag = "1" value="5" />`

Comment: What do you mean, "it doesn't work"? What are the symptoms?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="id">rating-input-1-<xsl:value-of select="./@value"/></xsl:attribute>
</xsl:copy>
```

--
P.S. Try to post more of your code. XSLT is very much context-dependent, and it's difficult to provide an answer when you're not sure of the current context. I am not even sure that is the best answer; I suspect it might be preferable to do:

```
<xsl:template match="input[@type='radio']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:attribute name="id">rating-input-1-<xsl:value-of select="./@value"/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

but I don't know if you *have* other templates to take care of the existing attributes.